# Check if XML Element Exists in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I need to check if an element exists in my XML that's retrieved from calling a web service. I need to run a certain function if a particular element does not exist.

Here is what I have so far. This works if all of these elements are there. I need to make sure the "MembershipNumber" element exists.

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

    attributes = attributeDict as NSDictionary

    element = elementName
    if ((elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "MembershipInfo")) {
        paidYear = ""
        county = ""
        name = ""
        dueDateString = ""
        membershipNumber = ""
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if element == "MembershipNumber" {
        membershipNumber.append(string)
        print("NUMBER: \(membershipNumber)")
    }
    if element == "County" {
        let counties = Counties().counties
        county.append(counties[string]!)
        print("COUNTY: \(county)")
    }

    if element == "PaidYear" {
        paidYear.append(string)
        print("PAID YEAR: \(paidYear)")
    }

    if element == "DueDate" {
        dueDateString.append(string)
        print("Due Date: \(dueDateString)")
    }

    if element == "Name" {
        if name == "" {
            name.append(string)
            print("NAME: \(name)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the names of all elements inside `didStartElement` in an array until this method called

```
 optional func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser)
```

then check the array content for that element  name

Answer (score 0):

You can do nice XML parsing with [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi).

Get XML document from XML string:

```
guard let xml = try? XMLDocument(string: xmlString) else {
    return
}
```

Get XML element with [XPath](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) if it exists:

```
guard let membershipNumber = xml.firstChild(xpath: "/MembershipNumber") else {
    return
}
```